# Excel Data Display in PHP Automatic show of set of rows

Tags: php

Hi I am  having issue in Displaying data in PHP
My Requirement  is I would like to Display excel Data in Table and Column 
with refresh in Data

I would like to Show  sets of  5 Rows at a time
refresh table and show next set of Rows

I am working on PHP with PHPExcel Objects already included

```
  <?php
             require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
//$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('N:\\DASH_BOARD_EXCEL.xls');
session_start();

$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('DASH_BOARD_EXCEL_2.xls');
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$i = 2;
while($excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' .$i)->getValue()!="")

for ($row = $i;$row <= 8 ;$row++) 
  {
{
$Chassis_Number =$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' .$i)->getValue();
$Inducted =$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' .$i)->getValue();
$Kit_Trolley =$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C' .$i)->getValue();
$cell = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D' . $i);  //Date Format change 
$Kit_SM_Parts= $cell->getValue();
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
     $Kit_SM_Parts = date($format = "d-M-Y", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($Kit_SM_Parts)); 
}
else {$Kit_SM_Parts =$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D' .$i)->getValue();}

$Seats =$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E' .$i)->getValue();
$i++;

}

?>
<?php
echo "<table border=1 bgcolor='#00CCFF' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed ;width:721pt'   text-align'=justify'   ; >";
echo "<td  height=15  align='center'   bgcolor='#003366' style='height:50.0pt'>" .$Chassis_Number. "</td>   ";
echo $cnt;


if ($Inducted == 'Yes' ||  $Inducted == 'Null' ){ echo "<td bgcolor='#003366' align='center' ; >Yes</td>"; } else{echo "<td bgcolor='#FF6600' align='center' >Work in Progress</td>";}  

if ($Kit_Trolley == 'Yes' ||  $Kit_Trolley == 'Null' ){ echo "<td bgcolor='#003366' align='center'>Yes</td>"; } else{echo "<td bgcolor='#FF6600' align='center' >Work in Progress</td>";}

if ($Kit_SM_Parts == 'Yes' ||  $Kit_SM_Parts == 'Null' ){ echo "<td bgcolor='#003366' align='center' ; >Yes</td>"; } else{echo "<td bgcolor='#FF6600'>Work in Progress</td>";}      

if ($Seats == 'Yes' ||  $Seats == 'Null' ){ echo "<td bgcolor='#003366' align='center';>Yes</td>"; } else{echo "<td bgcolor='#FF6600' align='center'>Work in Progress</td>";}   
echo "</table>";
} 

?>

     </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Code mentioned above is the Fetch from the  Excel Sheet already  getting displayed for 7 Rows

But  I would like to  Show next  8 and So on till the End of the rows and Again repeat the  same with   first 8

there are no error so far

Would like to Show set of  records /Rows Continuously -Automatically  changing after every set of  Rows

## My Excel sheet date :

1 CHDWD250819001    Yes  Yes    Yes Yes

2 CHDWD250819002    Yes

3 CHDWD250819003    Yes  Yes    Yes Yes

4 CHDWD250819004    Yes  Yes    Yes Yes

5 CHDWD250819005    Yes

Comment: I think the technical term you are looking for is paginate or page.

Answer (score 0):

here is code that could help you

```
  <?php   

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1";   

    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);   

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);   

    $total_records = $row[0];   



    // Number of pages required. 

    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);   

    $pagLink = "";                         

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

      if ($i==$pn) { 

          $pagLink .= "<li class='active'><a href='index.php?page="

                                            .$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; 

      }             

      else  { 

          $pagLink .= "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'> 

                                            ".$i."</a></li>";   

      } 

    };   

    echo $pagLink;   

  ?> 

  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank for the Support
But  I am Looking for  Excel sheet data and  count
how can I  count the total  Rows  ?